# Different uniqid when calld in wp_localize_script and shortcode

Tags: shortcode, ajax, wp-localize-script

So I am making a shortcode and trying to integrate vue + wp_query and having difficulty in making it work when I use multiple shortcodes on the same page with different attributes. I am using the code of the plugin "Simple instant search" as a base and am still learning things.

I thought I could use uniqid() for the div id and wp_localize_script and then use it in the script file. However the id generated in the div is different from the id generated in the js -`vfm_gallery.block_id`.

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('myclass')){
    class myclass {

        /**
         * Class Constractor
         */
        function __construct() {
            //add shortcode
            add_shortcode('gallery-grid', array($this,'display_gallery_shortcode'));
            //ajax handler
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_vfm_gallery', array($this, 'ajax_search') );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_vfm_gallery',  array($this, 'ajax_search') );
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',array($this,'add_scripts_and_styles'));

        }

        /**
         * shortcode to display search form and results Div
         * @return string - search form and results Div
         */
        public function display_gallery_shortcode(){

            return  '<div id="' . $this->gallery_block_id() . '">
                        <transition name="fade">
                            <div class="loader-overlay" v-if="loading">
                                <div class="loader"></div>
                                <h2>Fetching data</h2>
                            </div>
                        </transition>
                        <transition name="slide-fade" appear>
                            <div v-if="!loading">
                                <ul>
                                    <li v-for="post in posts">
                                        {{ post.title }}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </transition>
                    </div>';

        }

        /**
         * ajax search function
         * @return array() with title,content JSON
         */
        public function ajax_search(){


            $latest = new WP_Query( array (
                'post_type'       => 'gallery',
                'posts_per_page'  => '9',
                'cat'             => '',
            ));

            $posts = $latest->posts;

            // Check if any posts were found.
            if ( ! $latest->post_count ){
                echo json_encode(array());
                die();
            }


            //Create an array with the results

            $results=array();
            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {   

                $video_url = $post->post_content;

                $title = trim( strip_tags( $post->post_title ) );

                $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail' );

                $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

                $results[] = array(
                  'title'       => $title,
                  'video_url'   => $video_url,
                  'image'       => $image,
                  'url'         => $url
                );
            }

            //using JSON to encode the array
            echo json_encode($results);
            die();
        }

        /**
         * Void function to add needed scripts and styles.
         */
        public function add_scripts_and_styles(){
            wp_enqueue_script( 'vfm-gallery', plugin_dir_url(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . 'js/gallery.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );

            wp_localize_script( 'vfm-gallery', 'vfm_gallery', array(
                'ajaxUrl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'nonce'     => wp_create_nonce('vfmg'),
                'block_id'  => $this->gallery_block_id()
            ));
        }

        static function gallery_block_id(){
            return 'vfm_gallery_' . uniqid();
        }


    }//end class
}//end if
new myclass();
```

```
var postsList = new Vue({
    el: "#" + vfm_gallery.block_id,
    data: {
        posts: [],
        loading: true,
    },
    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {

            this.loading = true; //start loading
            axios.get(vfm_gallery.ajaxUrl, {
                    params: {
                        action: 'vfm_gallery',
                        nonce: vfm_gallery.nonce
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.loading = false; //stop loading
                    this.posts = response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.loading = false; //stop loading
                    console.error(error)
                })

        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the **__construct()** you can put this

```
global $shortcode_id;
$shortcode_id = 0;
```

in the **display_gallery_shortcode()** function you can do this

```
<?php 
global $shortcode_id;
$shortcode_id ++;
$settings_arr = array();//Here is your settings for each shortcode
ob_start();
?>

<script> 
if(!my_plugin_data) var my_plugin_data = {}
my_plugin_data[<?php echo $shortcode_id ?>] = <?php echo json_encode($settings_arr) ?>
</script>
<div>MY SHORTCODE CONTENT GOES HERE</div>

<?php 
return ob_get_clean();
```

Try to reload the page and check the variable in the javascript console.

```
console.log(my_plugin_data);
```